# Java:: Module(s) within module?

Tags: java, module, module-info

Is module(s) within module supported in Java Platform Module System (JPMS)? Is it a good practice?

Let's take the following structure as an example. I did not include the *module descriptors* (`module-info.java`) for the `outermodule1` and the root module (?) which is named `modulewithinmodule`.

[image]

I find having this nested structure useful for managing my dependencies using Maven modules. The configuration and encapsulation of all the (JPMS) modules with a module descriptor work as expected as well.

For my project to be, according to JPMS, fully modularized, should I include a module descriptor for the modules that do not have one now? If so, what directive (command) should I use (if any) for the inner-modules? If not, then they are considered an *unnamed module* and consequently, will depend on all the java-base modules (and possibly others) whether they are needed or not and make the application heavier; correct?

Comment: No, JPMS does not support modules within modules. However, what you're doing with Maven modules should be okay. Even though you have a Maven module "within" an outer module they are still separate modules.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the reply. So is my last sentence correct? Note that `outermodule1` only contains modules (and one `pom` file) Does this make the application depend on all java modules (whether or not they are needed)?

Comment: @Slaw Alternatively, is there a way for me to inquire a command to tell me which modules are *named* which are *unnamed* (and possibly which are *Automatic*)?

Comment: Maven modules either output artifacts, serve as common configuration for sub-modules, or both (at least, I'm pretty sure; I'm more familiar with Gradle). You only need JPMS module-info descriptors for those Maven modules which actually compile Java code. In your setup, neither the root Maven module nor the `outermodule1` Maven module build any Java code, let alone a JPMS module. Note that Maven is only a build tool. Once you package and deploy your application, Maven is no longer in the picture.

Comment: As for your second comment, the _unnamed module_ is special. That's the module where all code placed on the class-path ends up. By definition, if code is placed on the module-path then it cannot be in the _unnamed module_. Named modules can either be automatic or not. An automatic module does not have a `module-info` descriptor. I believe you can see if a JAR file is an automatic module or not by using `jar` with the `--describe-module` option. There may also be something you can do with `jdeps` or maybe even `java`, but not sure.

Comment: What consequences should this “inner module” relationship have? You can name your modules `foo.bar.baz` and `foo.bar.blah` to indicate a relationship, similar to packages. You can use qualified exports to allow only specific modules access to packages, similar to inner class relationships. Having a special source directory structure is also possible, though it adds some challenges to the build environment, while, on the other hand, has no consequences to the compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Slaw's answers, and a bit more research the following is what I have gathered. Correct me if I am wrong.

1. The nested JPMS modules are not supported.
2. The above file structure would not result in any nested JPMS structure, and no *unnamed* JPMS module exists. The compiler should have access to module paths and Maven takes care of that. Note, however, that Maven modules are nested.
3. According to [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/unnamed-modules.html), although *the unnamed* module requires all other named modules automatically, they are only loaded on demand.